# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu onto 2 different SSD, with an ESP already present in the system. Ubuntu won't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, ssd

I have an SSD with Windows 10 installed. Some time ago I installed Linux Mint 21-Cinnamon on an SD card and during the installation, I selected the SSD as the device on which to install the boot partition. It worked fine.

Now I bought a new SSD to replace the DVD drive and decided to install Linux on it.

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop, but on reboot it was not recognized in the boot menu. I then ran the Boot-Repair tool and now it is recognized, but if I select it at the first option, it is skipped.

This is the [link to boot-repair log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VNks4Ycqn2/).

```
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi of sdb2,
using the following options:  sdb1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups

/boot/efi added in sdb2/fstab
rm /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
Mount sdb1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2/boot/efi
ls: cannot access '/mnt/boot-sav/sdb2/boot/efi/efi': No such file or directory
No sdb2/boot/efi/efi/ ubuntu/mint folder

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sdb2/etc/default/grub

======================== Reinstall the grub-efi of sdb2 ========================

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2 grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7.1
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2 modprobe efivars

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2 efibootmgr -v before grub install
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0004,0001,2003,2001,2002
Boot0000* Linpus lite   HD(1,GPT,023a070c-2089-4b9a-8e93-0098183c5315,0x800,0x1cd1239)/File(EFIBootgrubx64.efi)RC
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,71062af1-606a-4b2b-96c3-ca87879f82b9,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0002* EFI Network 0 for IPv4 (54-E1-AD-7E-06-EB)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(54e1ad7e06eb,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0003* EFI Network 0 for IPv6 (54-E1-AD-7E-06-EB)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(54e1ad7e06eb,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,71062af1-606a-4b2b-96c3-ca87879f82b9,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2 uname -r
5.19.0-32-generic

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/sdb1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2/boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
df /dev/sda1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2/boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2 efibootmgr -v after grub install
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0004,0001,2003,2001,2002
Boot0000* Linpus lite   HD(1,GPT,023a070c-2089-4b9a-8e93-0098183c5315,0x800,0x1cd1239)/File(EFIBootgrubx64.efi)RC
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,71062af1-606a-4b2b-96c3-ca87879f82b9,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0002* EFI Network 0 for IPv4 (54-E1-AD-7E-06-EB)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(54e1ad7e06eb,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0003* EFI Network 0 for IPv6 (54-E1-AD-7E-06-EB)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(54e1ad7e06eb,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,71062af1-606a-4b2b-96c3-ca87879f82b9,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
Warning: NVram was not modified.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-32-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sdb2/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS entry (sdb1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/pop/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on sdb2
OS#2:   Windows 10 or 11 on sda3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: UHD Graphics 620 GP108M [GeForce MX150] from Intel Corporation NVIDIA Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 6JCN33WW(1.33) from LENOVO
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0004,0001,2003,2001,2002
Boot0000* Linpus lite   HD(1,GPT,023a070c-2089-4b9a-8e93-0098183c5315,0x800,0x1cd1239)/File(\EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,71062af1-606a-4b2b-96c3-ca87879f82b9,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0002* EFI Network 0 for IPv4 (54-E1-AD-7E-06-EB)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(54e1ad7e06eb,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0003* EFI Network 0 for IPv6 (54-E1-AD-7E-06-EB)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(54e1ad7e06eb,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,71062af1-606a-4b2b-96c3-ca87879f82b9,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC

64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda1/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
5ddf997e8b025bfbc2009e85b32f60dc   sda1/Boot/bootx64.efi
a9c517741ac31962d7feb152948ad1ee   sda1/Boot/fbx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sda1/Boot/mmx64.efi
5ddf997e8b025bfbc2009e85b32f60dc   sda1/pop/grubx64.efi
256fe27540b54b71cf38110338247688   sda1/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi
5ddf997e8b025bfbc2009e85b32f60dc   sda1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sda1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
20ac8dde00311476f3755604eb0e545a   sda1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
27d382c5fc21df6f4a75baed05aa1d9d   sda1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sdb1/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sdb1/BOOT/bootx64.efi
a9c517741ac31962d7feb152948ad1ee   sdb1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sdb1/BOOT/mmx64.efi
5ddf997e8b025bfbc2009e85b32f60dc   sdb1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sdb1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sdb1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdb : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda3    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda4    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sdb2    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb2    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda3    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda4    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sdb1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb2    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sdb

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0D0259B0-D3B2-4F00-A01A-90F7DA2B775B
          Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1       2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
sda2     206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
sda3     239616 975703472 975463857 465.1G Microsoft basic data
sda4  975704064 976771071   1067008   521M Windows recovery environment
Disk sdb: 223.57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk identifier: 6C0F5745-0215-429B-AEAD-46BD32A4BD0D
       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sdb1    2048    194559    192512    94M EFI System
sdb2  194560 468860927 468666368 223.5G Linux filesystem
Disk sdc: 14.41 GiB, 15472047104 bytes, 30218842 sectors
Disk identifier: 24EE2E2B-B119-4F75-BA03-B0CA96BAC5EF
      Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sdc1   2048 30218808 30216761 14.4G Microsoft basic data

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:500GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA CT500MX500SSD1:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:106MB:123MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:123MB:500GB:499GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:500GB:500GB:546MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;
sdb:240GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA KINGSTON SA400S3:;
1:1049kB:99.6MB:98.6MB:fat32::boot, esp;
2:99.6MB:240GB:240GB:ext4::;
sdc:15.5GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:Kingston DataTraveler 3.0:;
1:1049kB:15.5GB:15.5GB:fat32:Main Data Partition:msftdata;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                   
├─sda1 vfat     3E3B-0CD2                            71062af1-606a-4b2b-96c3-ca87879f82b9             EFI system partition
├─sda2                                               d0d76e72-3893-4644-83db-99df50e63140             Microsoft reserved partition
├─sda3 ntfs     7EDE43ECDE439B73                     5cef84cb-ea29-4150-bc4b-2cb859d42a57             Basic data partition
└─sda4 ntfs     EEC6B4BBC6B484FD                     ed65363d-91a7-4f4c-97c0-68a95aa57e58             
sdb                                                                                                   
├─sdb1 vfat     CA06-9BA7                            dff681cb-a316-4cb3-9621-a0e5a8138e4d             
└─sdb2 ext4     c9205750-fd10-4aa8-b206-cfcc37f4211a 65441d21-1210-4294-932b-b55ef1df4555             
sdc                                                                                                   
└─sdc1 vfat     3C94-09CF                            023a070c-2089-4b9a-8e93-0098183c5315 UBUNTU 22_0 Main Data Partition

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                           Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                  59.9M  38% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda3                   239G  49% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sda4                  88.7M  83% /mnt/boot-sav/sda4
/dev/sdb1                  85.6M   8% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1
/dev/sdb2                 200.5G   3% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2
/dev/sdc1                   9.8G  32% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


===================== sda1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid c9205750-fd10-4aa8-b206-cfcc37f4211a root hd1,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

===================== sdb1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid c9205750-fd10-4aa8-b206-cfcc37f4211a root hd1,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sdb2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   c9205750-fd10-4aa8-b206-cfcc37f4211a
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-35-generic   c9205750-fd10-4aa8-b206-cfcc37f4211a
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-32-generic   c9205750-fd10-4aa8-b206-cfcc37f4211a
Windows Boot Manager (on sda1)   osprober-efi-3E3B-0CD2
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sdb2/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=c9205750-fd10-4aa8-b206-cfcc37f4211a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=CA06-9BA7  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

======================= sdb2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

==================== sdb2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
  64.033809662 = 68.755779584   boot/vmlinuz                                   2
  38.268184662 = 41.090150400   boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-32-generic                 2
  64.033809662 = 68.755779584   boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-35-generic                 2
  38.268184662 = 41.090150400   boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 153.268539429 = 164.570841088  boot/initrd.img                                1
 152.971427917 = 164.251820032  boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-32-generic              1
 153.268539429 = 164.570841088  boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-35-generic              1
 152.971427917 = 164.251820032  boot/initrd.img.old                            1

===================== sdb2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Dec  2 15:18 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Dec  2 15:18 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14180 Dec  2 15:18 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Dec  2 15:18 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Dec  2 15:18 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Sep 20 03:18 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec  2 15:18 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec  2 15:18 41_custom

====================== sdc1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sdc1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

I don't know how to solve it. Here are some photos:

`/dev/sda` is the main SSD where is installed Windows.
`/dev/sdb` is the new SSD, installed in the DVD spot.

- Boot menu:

  [image: Boot menu]
- `fdisk -l` command:

  [image: fdisk -l command]
- GParted of `/dev/sda`:

  [image: Gparted of /dev/sda]
- GParted of `/dev/sdb`:

  [image: Gparted of /dev/sdb]

I disabled the Windows fast boot option in the energy settings and in the BIOS, and also the secure boot.

Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try putting ubuntu first in the boot sequence instead of third.  Try the EFI menu at power-up (some key to allow you to select device/os to boot) and select ubuntu.

Comment: @ubfan1 many thanks for your message. In the end I was able to solve the problem: it was the interl RTS techology that deny the second SSD to boot. Thanks anyway for the help :)